Help with calculating the coefficients of the product of polynomials
Recently, I have encountered some difficulties in calculating the coefficients of a polynomial in the following problem:
For any given $i$, define the function $f_i$ as follows:
$$f_i(x) = \left(a_{i}x - \frac{1}{2}a_{i}^{3}x^{3}\right)\prod_{j<i,j\in\mathcal{A}}\left[b_{j} - \left(a_{j}x^{3} - \frac{1}{2}a_{j}^{3}x^{5}\right)\right],$$
where $a_{i},b_{j}$ are all known coefficients and $\mathcal{A}$ denotes the set of all possible values of $j$ that satisfy some given conditions.
This function can be approximated near $x=0$ as:
$$f_i(x) \approx a_iB_ix - \frac12a_i^3B_ix^3+ C_{i,j} x^4+ \mathrm{o}(x^4),$$
where $B_i=\prod_{j<i,j\in\mathcal A}b_j$.
My question is: What is the specific form of $C_{i,j}$?
I would greatly appreciate any guidance you can provide.
